# Div floating problem

Tags: css, css-float

http://jsbin.com/aruvo4/5

How can I make the 3rd div go immediately under the first div?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889230/css-block-float-left

Answer (score 1):

you can add `float:right;` for the `#wrapper .long`

example: http://jsbin.com/aruvo4/4

Also, add `overflow:auto` for your `#wrapper` to clear the floats. 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: The longer divs don't have any class. The text they contain vary in length. Should have made that clearer. Thank's anyway.

Comment: @SuprDewd in your first example it had. You can't add a class for the long div? If not you can use javascript to select and apply it properties, or using `nth-child()` pseudo-class, to select it, like `div#wrapper div:nth-child(2) {float:right;}`. But this will not work for ie8 under below.

Comment: I can't use :nth-child() because some divs are longer than other, and I don't have a way of detecting which of them are. The number of divs may also varies.

Comment: @SuprDewd you can use javascript to detect the height of each element.

Comment: That's my last resort... Is there really no better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS3 solution for you:

```
#wrapper { width: 200px; overflow: auto; }
#wrapper div { float: left; background: pink; min-height: 80px; width: 80px; margin: 5px; padding: 4px; }
#wrapper div:nth-child(2) { float: right; }
```

For a cross-browser solution, though, you'll need to add a class to the div I've floated right

:nth-child browser support

```
IE8   FF3.5+  SA3.1+  OP9.5+  CH2+
None  Full    Full    Full    Full
```

-- edit --

Just read some more comments on here and seen that you can't use the pseudo class. I'll keep the answer here though as it will work in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Organize it as you would a table (i.e., place div tags around your 'rows') and set the div's display properties to `table-row` and `table-cell` as appropriate. The long cell needs to have top and bottom =0 and position set to absolute. There also needs to be a blank cell holding the place of the long allowing it to stretch down.

Here's a complete [explanation](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2008/09/09/rowspans-colspans-in-css-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="small_divs">
</div>
<div class="small_divs">
</div>
<div class="small_divs">
</div>
<div id="big_div>
</div>

#big_div { float:right;}
```