# When positioning a div below floated divs of mixed height, how to align to bottom of shorter div?

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have elements structured roughly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zyySd/

Is there any way to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/zyySd/1/

without resorting to taking the elements out of the document's flow and hardcoding absolute positioning values? In the case that I don't know what the dimensions of the divs are, I would not be able to use absolute position as I did in the second JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS [can't really do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003171/css-two-columns-with-known-children-width/6003261#6003261). You need JavaScript.

jQuery Masonry is good: http://masonry.desandro.com/

There's also a no-framework version, Vanilla Masonry: http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/