# How to achieve float: top in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

If you can read the Headings ... one's called JWT, the other Alela Diane.. how do I get "Alela Diane" to fill up the space between them ( no puns intended )

The CSS property for these div's is set to display: inline-block.

[image]

The HTML - >

```
<div id="shastra_display">

<div class="shastra_post">
  There are multiple div's like this containing the Alela Diane's and JWT's etc.
</div> 

</div>
```

The CSS - >

```
#shastra_display
{
    width: 880px;
}

#shastra_display div
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.shastra_post
{
    width: 270px;
    background-color: light-grey;
}
```

Comment: can you put some code...so we can work with and findout the solution

Comment: Is it always going to be just two columns?

Comment: It's two columns because the width of the parent box allows only two to fit.

Comment: I want it to be 3 columns actually but that's not a problem as far as I see

Comment: @Anish - Check the edit, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

> Is it always going to be just two
>   columns? – thirtydot
>
> It's two columns because the width of
>   the parent box allows only two to fit.
>   – Zach

So, the number of columns changes depending on the browser width.

That means you can't "cheat" and do it like this (as suggested by @Stefy):

- http://jsbin.com/atimu4

Other than a fixed number of columns, CSS can't do it. See this answer for a comparision of the ideas:

- [CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights/5234858#5234858)

You will have to use JavaScript. There's already a convienient jQuery plugin: [**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)

Some interesting demos:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-jquery.html
- http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

Comment: Thanks for this man, I'm trying it out. Will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a 2-column template in order to display the items properly.