# How to simulate a float:top in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a large list of items that I want floated, but ideally I want them to stack top to bottom, left to right. Floating left stacks them left to right, top to bottom.

How can I simulate a css float:top attribute in javascript in either native code or jQuery?

Example code:

```
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul {
    height:80px;
    width:350px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
    outline:1px solid;
}
li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:3px 5px;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>1679</li>
    <li>1682</li>
    <li>1732</li>
    <li>1761</li>
    <li>1773</li>
    <li>1781</li>
    <li>1788</li>
    <li>1791</li>
    <li>1797</li>
    <li>1799</li>
    <li>1832</li>
    <li>1861</li>
    <li>1873</li>
    <li>1879</li>
    <li>1881</li>
    <li>1882</li>
    <li>1888</li>
    <li>1891</li>
    <li>1897</li>
    <li>1899</li>
    <li>1932</li>
    <li>1932</li>
    <li>1961</li>
    <li>1961</li>
</ul>
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847460/how-can-i-make-a-float-top-with-css), but it seems to be looking for more of a CSS solution rather than a js based solution. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123246/how-to-achieve-float-top-in-css-html) is a more specific implementation of a layout fix.

Comment: I'm confused about what your question is. You say you want them top to bottom, left to right and that's exactly what floating left will do. So what's the problem?

Comment: what is `float: top`? there are only 4 options: left, right, none, or inherit.

Comment: @Sang - there is no float top, that is only a descriptor of what he would *like* to exist.

Comment: Ok, so what he's describing are *columns*.

Comment: @DanGayle - finally found the SO question that asked this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268447/how-to-stack-divs-from-top-to-bottom-in-css

Comment: `-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg)` :D

Comment: @Geuis Not necessarily columns, in much the same way that floating left or right doesn't create rows.

Comment: Who is downvoting this question? If there's a problem with the question, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

http://masonry.desandro.com/

jQuery Masonry does **exactly** what you're describing. And it's super easy to implement. You may have to alter your markup slightly, though.

Comment: I had seen jQuery Masonry before. I'll definitely check it out to see if it will do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into css3 multi columns. http://caniuse.com/#search=column

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me, called on window resize/change of list

```
function layout(oList) {
    var column = 0,
        top = 0,
        bottomMargin=20,
        width = 300;

        $(oList).each(function () {
            if (top !=0 && $(this).height() + top > $(window).height()) {
                top = 0;
                column += 1;
            }
            $(this).css("top", top + "px");
            $(this).css("left", (column * width) + "px");
            top = top + $(this).height() + bottomMargin;
        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can make smart columms. Here's a jsfiddle that will adapt to different heights and widths of each li ensuring smooth columns: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/hAeQ2/

```
var list, currentColLeft, currentColTop, nextColWidth;
currentColLeft = currentColTop = nextColWidth = 0;
list = $('ul#list');
$('ul > li').each(function(i, el){
    var h, w;
    h = $(el).outerHeight();
    w = $(el).outerWidth();
    if(currentColLeft + w > nextColWidth){
        nextColWidth = currentColLeft + w;
    }
    if(currentColTop + h > list.innerHeight()){
        currentColTop = 0;
        currentColLeft = nextColWidth;
        nextColWidth = 0;
    }
    $(el).css({'float':'none','position':'absolute','top':currentColTop,'left':currentColLeft});
    currentColTop += h;
});
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, something  you can do is loop over all of the li's and position them where you want them..

```
var origionalX = 100;
var origionalY = 200;
var columns = 10;
$("li").each(function(i){
  var x = origionalX+parseInt(i/columns)*$(this).width();
  var y = origionalY+(i%columns)*$(this).height();
  $(this).css({position : "absolute", left : x, top : y});
});
```

Hopefully that will help a little bit. If you're wanting something more specific, feel free to comment and i'll see if i can help. :]

Comment: Can you think of a way to do this without setting the number of columns in advance?

Comment: What do you want to use as your signifier? you could easily set columns = total_width_of_area / width_of_each_item

Comment: Yeah, that sounds more reasonable. The width can actually be variable in my exact situation. Fixed height though.