# float variable height containers

Tags: css, layout, html

So i have x amount of "blocks" that I want to float left.. Like this :

A  B  C  D

E  F  G  H

BUT, if B is twice as long as the rest, for example, there would be white space between A & E, C & G, D & H.

How can I avoid that and just have all the containers float to the left and then fit in nicely without excess white space in between ?

Comment: Check this out: http://masonry.desandro.com/?resources/jquery-masonry It's not exactly what you're asking, but you might get some good ideas from it.

Answer (score 2):

CSS cannot handle this in the general case.

If there are a fixed number of columns, you can cheat and do this: http://jsfiddle.net/suaaK/11/

Otherwise:

See this answer for a comparison of the candidate techniques, showing that they don't work:

- [CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights/5234858#5234858)

If you're willing to use JavaScript, you should use [**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html).

Demos:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-css-transitions.html
- http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

Comment: on second thought, doesn't really work for me.  I have some dynamic elements in some of the blocks, some which starts hidden, and masonry doesn't seem to cope so well with that.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your CSS into vertical columns versus horizontals. Smashing Magazine has a great piece about floats and their quirks, go take a look: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/