# CSS Stacked divs

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I have some divs which are all floating left, If you see the attached jsfiddle you will see what im trying to do, in the fiddle there is a yellow box, I need this to be flush with the bottom of the green box only im not sure if this is even possible?

Is it? and if so how may I do this? Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/K5zjc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/jUyar/)**. Techincally, you float even `.box` items to the right instead of left and then you are getting self-filling columns in accordance to their content. So, in your CSS you add:

```
.box:nth-child(odd) {clear: left}
.box:nth-child(even) {float: right; clear: right}
```

*UPDATE*

Apparently this solution doesn't work nice if you have more than these specific blocks. So, probably, [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) is the only way for you to get the good result.

Comment: Yeah, I think jQuery Masonry is the easiest way to achieve what is needed here if the height of the containers and their number is not known.

Comment: I guess he only needed those four boxes and doesn't care about older browsers and *really* didn't want to change the HTML. So your answer was better for him.

Answer (score 1):

You must add two `div`s with `float: left` that act as columns.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/K5zjc/5/

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <div class="box green">
            <ul><li>Item</li></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box yellow">
            <ul><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxContainer">
        <div class="box red">
            <ul><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box cyan">
            <ul><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My only problem is im working with an existing .net website where the items are generated on the fly so I'm unaware of how to wrap X amount of items in 1 column and X in the other.

Comment: I can't help you with the server-side part. From a front-end point of view, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378524/float-variable-height-containers/6378690#6378690. You might find using jQuery Masonry easier, especially if you're already using JavaScript/jQuery.