# Align floated divs top to bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have one article tag, inside a php code that generate articles from wordpress. They are not all the same height ofc, it depends on the content. They are organised in two columns by float.

If a article in the first line is not the same height as the other one in the same row, the second row is aligned to the bottom of the biger div. Now I want to align them without any spacing.

Here is some css:

```
#container {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

article {
position: relative;
width: 435px;
margin: 10px 10px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 20px;
float: left;
}
```

Edit jsFiddle (now with content to demonstrate the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/4PMj5/6/

Comment: Remove `margin: 10px 10px;`?

Comment: here article is class or id?

Comment: @Morpheus margin is not a problem

Comment: @Emir Dupovac would be nice if you could create jsfiddle example of your problem

Comment: @Morpheus I can't beacuse it is wordpress generated

Comment: @EmirDupovac You can still create a static example with the relevant HTML structure.

Comment: ok, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4PMj5/4/

Comment: Please explain what "Now I want to align them without any spacing." really means

Comment: @EmirDupovac Please could you provide an illustration of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have a look at the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights). [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) may help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JSantos http://jsfiddle.net/4PMj5/8/ take a look at big empty white

Comment: @EmirDupovac I see you already have the answer, but when I asked that, your jsfiddle wasnt showing anything like that new updated jsfiddle

Comment: @JSantos really sorry for bad explanation, and really this is correct answer, but it has some glitches, it has the same problem as this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4PMj5/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `even` and `odd` chilren pseudo selection in your CSS.

```
article:nth-child(even) {
    position: relative;
    width: 435px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 20px;
    float: right;
}
article:nth-child(odd) {
    position: relative;
    width: 435px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

The result will be like: [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PMj5/5/).