# Why html divs/spans don't lined up in order with float left?

Tags: css-float, html

I don't know if this is only my strange requirement, but I didn't really find anyone asking it before. My problem is:

When divs with random heights are floated in multiple rows why don't they stay in below the preceding number. I've noticed, the next row div goes below to the div which has less height in it's above row. Which makes blank space in the 2nd row and other following divs fall into next row. I've added fiddler link here `jsfiddle.net/GF9kE`

This image explains exactly what I mean. div 4 should have come below 1, 5 below 2, 6 below 3. But 4 went below 3 because 3 has least height. Why does this happen. And is there any fix to this ? I want to display divs in floating style but follow the order regardless of heights. [image]

I will be very thankful to you for reading this and helping me out.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not sure if this is defined in a standard or something but the explanation seems intuitive to me: if you're filling something right to left and up to down, then putting something in the first space that fits will do it, and if you align to the right and come up to down then the first space that is available it's below 3, not below 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great explanation I've seen written up about the topic is here.

http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/

The specific excerpt that addresses your question:

"Basically, the gist of the situation is that floated elements go right up to the specified edge (left or right), but no further. Unless of course there is another floated element before it, in which case it just goes next to that one.

The real surprise that confused us before comes in the rules at the end, which state that floated elements try to stay as high as possible and that this vertical positioning rule takes precedence over the horizontal left/right floating rule that pushes an item to an edge."

Short answer - Since box #2 stretches the line height to be greater than the height of #3, #4 has some room to squeeze in before the next line starts.  Similar logic applies to #8 and #9.

--- EDIT ---

If you want your boxes to flow in a Pinterest-style fashion, your best bet is to use an existing javascript library such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Blocksit](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/).

If you want to try avoiding javascript and just use CSS3, [here's a good link you can check out](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout).  This might suit your needs depending on how much browser compat is necessary.

Comment: djpark, thanks. Your explanation is great and pretty understanding. But still it does not fix my problem. So I can't accept it as answer yet. Waiting for a solution....

Comment: By "fix your problem", I assume you mean have the boxes flow in a pinterest-style fashion.  I've edited my answer with how you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
They said with CSS alone we cannot get this done, please see here [CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights)