# Forcing div stack from left to right

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to force div elements to stack under each other no matter the height?

Currently this happens:
http://jsfiddle.net/w974mna9/

```css
div{
    width:24%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.one{
    background-color:red;
    height: 50px;
}

.two{
    background-color:green;
    height:35px;
}

.three{
    background-color:orange;
    height:45px;
}

.four{
    background-color:magenta;
    height:25px;
}

.five{
    background-color:black;
    height:55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
```

The first div that get forced into the next row stacks on the div with the lowest height and the others are pushed down one more row. I want to stack them from left to right in the order they are placed with the variable height indent on their upper siblings.

---

EDIT:
I don't want them to stack vertically, I want them to stack under each other in a row.

Comment: The OP has updated the question. The other answers do not provide a solution to this question.

Comment: @BDawg, I'ts ok, Lal or Paulie_D provided a link to the the answer. Pointed me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights). Thanks, masonry works like I need it to.

Comment: @Aleksandar_B. Okay, glad you found your answer. Just a side note: If you would like a simple, row-based solution without a Masonry layout, you could also use `inline-block` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/wLo8usv8/

Comment: I added an answer here: [**CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights/32109114#32109114) explaining why you can not achieve this using float.

Answer (score 1):

Add "clear" property for floating elements, for example

```
{
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `clear: both` to the `div` style, they will appear under each other.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w974mna9/1/)

Answer (score -2):

try

```
div{
    width:24%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```