# How to arrange Cards with different height in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

I;ve got these cards for example. And this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .card{
            width: 40%;
            height: 100px;
            border: 2px solid red;
            display: inline-table;
        }

        .last{
            height: 200px;
            border-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">test1</div>
    <div class="card">test2</div>
    <div class="card">test3</div>
    <div class="card last">test4</div>
    <div class="card">test5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to move **test5** block to top beside of **test4** and below of **test3** block...

how to arrange it with using css code on **.card** class???

Thank you

Comment: I think there maybe no easy solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights

Comment: Thank you :D I does solve mine